# React Native CLI version 0.64 setup Execution failed for task':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'. and Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Tags: java, gradle, react-native

## React Native First build Error

I wanted to setup my react native build and followed the steps Exactly from the environmental setup from the official react native documentation at version 0.64 with Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image part of the Android 10.0.
https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

Build:
https://github.com/NicChoo96/ReactNative0.64_Build

I have not even successfully build it and display the first react native screen on my emulator. The emulator is working fine.

I have also searched google for so many times, my tabs are just stacked but I cannot find any solution.

### Why not Expo

Having built and rebuilt for many days, for my use case, I wouldn't be able to use expo so I can only stick to using react-native-cli. In case you want to know what, I want to use web3.js/ether.js, but I cannot even get the basic build up, how to even start anything?

### My current tools and version

```
API Level: 29 (Android 10.0 Q)
Android SDK Build-Tools: 29.0.3
JDK: openjdk-8u292-b10

User variables for User:
ANDROID_HOME: %LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\OpenJDK\openjdk-8u292-b10
Node Version:v16.4.0
Yarn Version: 1.22.10

Path: 
{ 
  C:\Program Files\OpenJDK\openjdk-8u292-b10\bin,
  %LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\Sdk\platform-tools,
  %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\emulator
} ​
```

### Error Logs

The errors below is what has shown up building again and again:

#### checkDebugDuplicateClasses error

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource found in modules jetified-react-native-0.20.1-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.20.1) and jetified-soloader-0.10.1-runtime (com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.1)
     Duplicate class com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource found in modules jetified-react-native-0.20.1-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.20.1) and jetified-soloader-0.10.1-runtime (com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.1)
     Duplicate class com.facebook.soloader.Elf32_Dyn found in modules jetified-react-native-0.20.1-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.20.1) and jetified-soloader-0.10.1-runtime (com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.1)
     Duplicate class com.facebook.soloader.Elf32_Ehdr found in modules jetified-react-native-0.20.1-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.20.1) and jetified-soloader-0.10.1-runtime (com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.1)
     Duplicate class com.facebook.soloader.Elf32_Phdr found in modules jetified-react-native-0.20.1-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.20.1) and jetified-soloader-0.10.1-runtime (com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.1)
     Duplicate class com.facebook.soloader.Elf32_Shdr found in modules jetified-react-native-0.20.1-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.20.1) and jetified-soloader-0.10.1-runtime (com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.1)
     Duplicate class com.facebook.soloader.Elf64_Dyn found in modules jetified-react-native-0.20.1-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.20.1) and jetified-soloader-0.10.1-runtime (com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.1)
     Duplicate class com.facebook.soloader.Elf64_Ehdr found in modules jetified-react-native-0.20.1-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.20.1) and jetified-soloader-0.10.1-runtime (com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.1)
     Duplicate class com.facebook.soloader.Elf64_Phdr found in modules jetified-react-native-0.20.1-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.20.1) and jetified-soloader-0.10.1-runtime (com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.1)
     Duplicate class com.facebook.soloader.Elf64_Shdr found in modules jetified-react-native-0.20.1-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.20.1) and jetified-soloader-0.10.1-runtime (com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.1)
     Duplicate class com.facebook.soloader.ExoSoSource found in modules jetified-react-native-0.20.1-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.20.1) and jetified-soloader-0.10.1-runtime (com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.1)
     Duplicate class com.facebook.soloader.FileLocker found in modules jetified-react-native-0.20.1-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.20.1) and jetified-soloader-0.10.1-runtime (com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.1)
     Duplicate class com.facebook.soloader.MinElf found in modules jetified-react-native-0.20.1-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.20.1) and jetified-soloader-0.10.1-runtime (com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.1)
     Duplicate class com.facebook.soloader.MinElf$ElfError found in modules jetified-react-native-0.20.1-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.20.1) and jetified-soloader-0.10.1-runtime (com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.1)
     Duplicate class com.facebook.soloader.NativeLibrary found in modules jetified-react-native-0.20.1-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.20.1) and jetified-soloader-0.10.1-runtime (com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.1)
     Duplicate class com.facebook.soloader.NoopSoSource found in modules jetified-react-native-0.20.1-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.20.1) and jetified-soloader-0.10.1-runtime (com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.1)
     Duplicate class com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader found in modules jetified-react-native-0.20.1-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.20.1) and jetified-soloader-0.10.1-runtime (com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.1)
     Duplicate class com.facebook.soloader.SoSource found in modules jetified-react-native-0.20.1-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.20.1) and jetified-soloader-0.10.1-runtime (com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.1)
     Duplicate class com.facebook.soloader.SysUtil found in modules jetified-react-native-0.20.1-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.20.1) and jetified-soloader-0.10.1-runtime (com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.1)
     Duplicate class com.facebook.soloader.SysUtil$LollipopSysdeps found in modules jetified-react-native-0.20.1-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.20.1) and jetified-soloader-0.10.1-runtime (com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.1)
```

#### compileDebugJavaWithJavac error

```
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
15 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 13 up-to-date
D:\1) ProjectsFolder\FYP\Learning\web3RN\android\app\src\main\java\com\web3rn\MainApplication.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
                         ^
  symbol:   class ReactApplication
  location: package com.facebook.react
D:\1) ProjectsFolder\FYP\Learning\web3RN\android\app\src\main\java\com\web3rn\MainApplication.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
                         ^
  symbol:   class ReactNativeHost
  location: package com.facebook.react
D:\1) ProjectsFolder\FYP\Learning\web3RN\android\app\src\main\java\com\web3rn\MainApplication.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {
                                                            ^
  symbol: class ReactApplication
D:\1) ProjectsFolder\FYP\Learning\web3RN\android\app\src\main\java\com\web3rn\MainApplication.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost =
                ^
  symbol:   class ReactNativeHost
  location: class MainApplication
D:\1) ProjectsFolder\FYP\Learning\web3RN\android\app\src\main\java\com\web3rn\MainApplication.java:39: error: cannot find symbol
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
         ^
  symbol:   class ReactNativeHost
  location: class MainApplication
D:\1) ProjectsFolder\FYP\Learning\web3RN\android\app\build\generated\rncli\src\main\java\com\facebook\react\PackageList.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainPackageConfig;
                               ^
  symbol:   class MainPackageConfig
  location: package com.facebook.react.shell
D:\1) ProjectsFolder\FYP\Learning\web3RN\android\app\build\generated\rncli\src\main\java\com\facebook\react\PackageList.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
  private ReactNativeHost reactNativeHost;
          ^
  symbol:   class ReactNativeHost
  location: class PackageList
D:\1) ProjectsFolder\FYP\Learning\web3RN\android\app\build\generated\rncli\src\main\java\com\facebook\react\PackageList.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
  private MainPackageConfig mConfig;
          ^
  symbol:   class MainPackageConfig
  location: class PackageList
D:\1) ProjectsFolder\FYP\Learning\web3RN\android\app\build\generated\rncli\src\main\java\com\facebook\react\PackageList.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
  public PackageList(ReactNativeHost reactNativeHost) {
                     ^
  symbol:   class ReactNativeHost
  location: class PackageList
D:\1) ProjectsFolder\FYP\Learning\web3RN\android\app\build\generated\rncli\src\main\java\com\facebook\react\PackageList.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
  public PackageList(ReactNativeHost reactNativeHost, MainPackageConfig config) {
                     ^
  symbol:   class ReactNativeHost
  location: class PackageList
D:\1) ProjectsFolder\FYP\Learning\web3RN\android\app\build\generated\rncli\src\main\java\com\facebook\react\PackageList.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
  public PackageList(ReactNativeHost reactNativeHost, MainPackageConfig config) {
                                                      ^
  symbol:   class MainPackageConfig
  location: class PackageList
D:\1) ProjectsFolder\FYP\Learning\web3RN\android\app\build\generated\rncli\src\main\java\com\facebook\react\PackageList.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
  public PackageList(Application application, MainPackageConfig config) {
                                              ^
  symbol:   class MainPackageConfig
  location: class PackageList
D:\1) ProjectsFolder\FYP\Learning\web3RN\android\app\build\generated\rncli\src\main\java\com\facebook\react\PackageList.java:40: error: cannot find symbol
  private ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
          ^
  symbol:   class ReactNativeHost
  location: class PackageList
D:\1) ProjectsFolder\FYP\Learning\web3RN\android\app\src\debug\java\com\web3rn\ReactNativeFlipper.java:25: error: package okhttp3 does not exist
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
              ^
D:\1) ProjectsFolder\FYP\Learning\web3RN\android\app\src\main\java\com\web3rn\MainActivity.java:5: error: MainActivity is not abstract and does not override abstract method getPackages() in ReactActivity
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
       ^
D:\1) ProjectsFolder\FYP\Learning\web3RN\android\app\src\main\java\com\web3rn\MainApplication.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
      new ReactNativeHost(this) {
          ^
  symbol:   class ReactNativeHost
  location: class MainApplication
D:\1) ProjectsFolder\FYP\Learning\web3RN\android\app\src\main\java\com\web3rn\MainApplication.java:18: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
        @Override
        ^
D:\1) ProjectsFolder\FYP\Learning\web3RN\android\app\src\main\java\com\web3rn\MainApplication.java:23: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
        @Override
        ^
D:\1) ProjectsFolder\FYP\Learning\web3RN\android\app\src\main\java\com\web3rn\MainApplication.java:32: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
        @Override
        ^
D:\1) ProjectsFolder\FYP\Learning\web3RN\android\app\src\main\java\com\web3rn\MainApplication.java:38: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
  @Override
  ^
D:\1) ProjectsFolder\FYP\Learning\web3RN\android\app\build\generated\rncli\src\main\java\com\facebook\react\PackageList.java:26: error: reference to PackageList is ambiguous
    this(application, null);
    ^
  both constructor PackageList(ReactNativeHost,MainPackageConfig) in PackageList and constructor PackageList(Application,MainPackageConfig) in PackageList match
D:\1) ProjectsFolder\FYP\Learning\web3RN\android\app\src\debug\java\com\web3rn\ReactNativeFlipper.java:40: error: cannot find symbol
          new NetworkingModule.CustomClientBuilder() {
                              ^
  symbol:   class CustomClientBuilder
  location: class NetworkingModule
D:\1) ProjectsFolder\FYP\Learning\web3RN\android\app\src\debug\java\com\web3rn\ReactNativeFlipper.java:42: error: package OkHttpClient does not exist
            public void apply(OkHttpClient.Builder builder) {
                                          ^
D:\1) ProjectsFolder\FYP\Learning\web3RN\android\app\src\debug\java\com\web3rn\ReactNativeFlipper.java:41: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
            @Override
            ^
D:\1) ProjectsFolder\FYP\Learning\web3RN\android\app\src\debug\java\com\web3rn\ReactNativeFlipper.java:57: error: cannot find symbol
                reactInstanceManager.removeReactInstanceEventListener(this);
                                    ^
  symbol:   method removeReactInstanceEventListener(<anonymous ReactInstanceEventListener>)
  location: variable reactInstanceManager of type ReactInstanceManager
Note: D:\1) ProjectsFolder\FYP\Learning\web3RN\android\app\src\debug\java\com\web3rn\ReactNativeFlipper.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
25 errors
```

## What I have tried

I have already try to mess around with JDK, JRE, build.gradle, build tool version. It seems that I have never escaped from these same error over and over again. Currently, I just want to know what is the underlying that is causing this errors despite my efforts of trying to get it working at all.

- Tried ./gradlew clean and build multiple times.
- Tried changing gradle version but unsure the accurate version as the
  template downloaded comes with build:gradle:4.1.0.
- Tried multiple JDK version: 1.8, openjdk-8u292-b10, 15.0.1
- Tried the implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+" to
  implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:0.64.0" but got an
  error of not allowing the change.
- Tried removing jcenter() from android/build.gradle but only just
  error.
- Tried changing compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion and
  minSdkVersion around but not to avail.
- Tried changing in this file but doesn't work

```
android/app/build.gradle
debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
      exclude group: 'com.facebook.soloader'
      exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }
```

Tried many and multiple ways, but I just have no clue which of these dependencies are causing this errors and stopping me to build even a Hello World Page.

## My build.gradle files that is the original templates, what I have tried is not included since none of them works

#### android/app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation. If none specified and
 *   // "index.android.js" exists, it will be used. Otherwise "index.js" is
 *   // default. Can be overridden with ENTRY_FILE environment variable.
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // https://reactnative.dev/docs/performance#enable-the-ram-format
 *   bundleCommand: "ram-bundle",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

/**
 * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore.
 *
 * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
 * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
 *
 * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
 * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
 * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US.  Note that
 * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
 */
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

/**
 * Whether to enable the Hermes VM.
 *
 * This should be set on project.ext.react and mirrored here.  If it is not set
 * on project.ext.react, JavaScript will not be compiled to Hermes Bytecode
 * and the benefits of using Hermes will therefore be sharply reduced.
 */
def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

android {
    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion

    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.awesomeproject"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }

    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            // Example: versionCode 1 will generate 1001 for armeabi-v7a, 1002 for x86, etc.
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        defaultConfig.versionCode * 1000 + versionCodes.get(abi)
            }

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
      exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }

    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

### android/build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 29
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```